# Firebase Cloud Messaging messaging/mismatched-credential

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to implement a push message service with Angular Service-Worker and Firebase.

The Service Worker registration to Firebase cloud messaging with the WebPush Certificate seems to work since i get the PushSubscription back. I store the subscription data in a firebase realtime database.

I use firebase-functions as backend, i initialize firebase-admin with the firebase-functions config.

My notification function retrieves the fcmToken from the database and use admin.messaging(fireadmin).sendToDevice(myToken, payload) to call the push service.

However in my function log, i get the error messaging/mismatched-credential

*The credential used to authenticate this SDK does not have permission to send messages to the device corresponding to the provided registration token. Make sure the credential and registration token both belong to the same Firebase project.*

-I have only one firebase project

-I have a firebase-admin service account and its key

-In my manifest i have the gcm_sender_id: "103953800507"

-I tried to enable the Firebase Cloud Messaging API through google cloud platform as advised in a similar question but did not see any change.

functions index.ts

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const fireadmin = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


interface Message {
  body: string;
  title: string;
}

exports.msgNotif = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onCreate( event => {
  console.log(functions.config().firebase);
  const mymessage = <Message>event.val();

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: mymessage.title,
      body: mymessage.body
    }
  };

  admin.database().ref('/fcmTokens/tEqlfyFohYV4221ACmbWxZZAGTi2').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  const fcmTokenUrl = <string>data['endpoint'];
  const fcmTokenUrlSplit = fcmTokenUrl.split('/');
  const myToken = fcmTokenUrlSplit[fcmTokenUrlSplit.length - 1];
  console.log(myToken);

  admin.messaging(fireadmin).sendToDevice(myToken, payload)
  .then( res => console.log(res.results.length, res.results[0].error, res.results[0].messageId, res.results[0].canonicalRegistrationToken)).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }).catch( err => console.log(err));
  return true;

});
```

messaging.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService implements OnInit {

  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private swPush: SwPush) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  subscribeToPush() {
    // Requesting messaging service to subscribe current client (browser)
    console.log('i want to subscribe');
    this.swPush.requestSubscription({
      serverPublicKey: 'key',
    })
      .then(pushSubscription => {
        // Passing subscription object to our backend
        console.log(pushSubscription);
        this.updateToken(pushSubscription);
        return;
      });
  }

  unsubscribeToPush() {
    this.swPush.subscription.take(1).subscribe(sub => {
      sub.unsubscribe()
      .then((result) => console.log('your service worker has been unsubscribed from the push service', result))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    });
  }

  updateToken(token) {
    return this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(user => {
      if (!user) { return; }

      const data = { [user.uid]: token };
      this.db.object('fcmTokens/').update(data)
        .then(() => console.log('it worked'))
        .catch(reason => console.log('it failed' + reason));
    });
  }

  showMessages() {
    this.swPush.messages
      .subscribe(message => {
        console.log('[App] Push message received', message);
      });
  }

  sendMessage() {
    const mynumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    const customMsg = 'msg' + mynumber.toString();
    const myobject = {
       [customMsg] : {
        title: 'a title',
        body: 'a body'
      }
    };

    console.log(myobject);
    return this.db.object('messages/tEqlfyFohYV4221ACmbWxZZAGTi2/').update(myobject);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you positive that the `registrationToken` you're sending the message to is associated with your FCM Project?

Comment: I am not sure, i would think the serverPublicKey that i send during the service worker subscription to FCM does the association since it comes from the firebase console (Web push Certificate under FCM parameters)

Comment: I would suggest checking if your using a registration token that is associated with your project. MismatchedSenderId is an error that occurs if the token you're sending a message to is not connected to the project you're sending the message from. Cheers!

Comment: Finally, i gave up on trying to make it work with firebase-admin, i've easily succeeded with the web-push library. If i had to say i think the problem was probably the firebase-admin configuration : webpush has the setGCMAPIKey and setVapidDetails methods to configure the connection, i don't know the equivalent with my first procedure.